# All ports are closed, even though I forwarded them on both my modem and router

Tags: port-forwarding, port

I wanted to open a certain port, but it didn't work. I portforwarded it on my Archer c5 router and on my Thomson TG789vn, but ping.eu still says it's closed...  I did a port scan with nmap and it turns out ALL my ports are closed.. can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're forwarding on two devices you have double NAT and no forwards can work properly.

Bridge the thompson and let the C5 route properly.